# Do I need to replace both front calipers because of a snapped bleeder valve?

Tags: vw, bleeding, caliper

Vw cc 2010 2.0l sport
I accidentally snapped the passenger right caliper bleeder valve while I was flushing my brake fluid.
A shop wants to charge me $670 to replace both calipers and the fluid. They said you usually replace calipers in pairs.

I was thinking. Do I need to replace calipers in pairs? And do I even need to replace the calipers themselves or can I just extract the bleeder screw with speedout and replace it.

Comment: I'm wondering why they are wanting to replace the caliper when you could probably get the old bleeder out and put a new one in its place? Just take a little bit of work to make it happen (IMHO).

Comment: I'm with @Paulster2 on this one, 670 bones to replace 2 calipers when all you need is a new bleed valve? Please.

Comment: Wow, $670 for two calipers and less than an hour of shop time. Do the mechanics drive Rolls Royce's at this shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brake **pads** should be replaced in pairs, that is to make sure you get even braking action. Calipers do **not** need to be replaced in pairs I would suspect anyone telling you that wants to rip you off. A broken bleed screw is not a reason to replace a caliper unless the remains cannot be removed, even then a reconditioned one would be my solution, and only on the side that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The calipers do not always need to be replaced in pairs. If the shop looked at the calipers they may have determined that the odds of getting the bleeders out is too low. Depending on the shops hourly rate they may have determined that it is more cost effective to just replace the calipers. Sometimes this is a liability decision. If the caliper is overheated to free the bleeder it could fail prematurely. The other concern may be charging for 1/2hour of labor to get the bleeder out and find out the piston sticks and it needs to be replaced anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to speak to an engineering firm, either that or buy a set of easy outs.

When I've snapped off bleed screws on VW's in the past, I've always had success at removing the remains of the snapped bleed screw by sending an easy out (screw extractor) down the bit that's left.

If you can't extract the snapped bleed screw this way, speak to an engineering shop.  They ought to be able to put the caliper on the bench and remove the bleed screw.  Even if it has to be drilled and retapped, even if you need to find an oversized bleed screw or add a helicoil, it won't come anywhere near the cost of replacing two calipers.

Of course, there is always the option of pulling the caliper off the yolk, placing a wind back tool into the caliper and bleeding it at the brake flexi hose instead of at the screw.